# create a subsite programmatically from list workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

So my situation is like this: A user adds the name and other information for creating a subsite in to a sharepoint list. The administrator of the site can approve or reject the craetion of the subsite.

Now my question is, can anyone help me how can I create a subsite from workflow?
Any code will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot guys,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this action to SharePoint Designer

http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2011/02/create-site-action-sharepoint-designer.html

and then create a workflow, that on approval of the item will create a site for you.

-p

Comment: is it possible to do it programmatically? The code has to be used in a solution.

Comment: you can create you custom workflow which does exact the same thing and deploy it as a wsp solution. here is my answer about site creation via code http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/programmatically-create-site-using-custom-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010/37394#37394

Comment: what is the easiest way and propably the best way, to create the workflow in SPD and export it to visual studio or write a custom workflow activity?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take the path of creating a custom workflow activity, this will allow for greater re-usability in the long run

Comment: can any one help me with an example?